# PGFPlots generates extra margin with restricted x axis and two y coordinates in standalone class

Tags: pgfplots, horizontal-alignment

I noticed that there are cases where `pgfplots` package makes undesirable (to me at least) margins. The conditions I've found is as follows:

- use `standalone` class
- use y coordinate on the right side
- read external data file (e.g. `.csv`), but all the data is not used for plotting
- content of the data does not matter

Consider the following sample code.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
    -5, 5, 2500
    -4, 4, 1600
    -3, 3, 900
    -2, 2, 400
    -1, 1, 100
    0, 0, 0
    1, -1, 100
    2, -2, 400
    3, -3, 900
    4, -4, 1600
    5, -5, 2500
\end{filecontents*}
%
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat = 1.12,
    set layers,
    scale only axis,
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[axis y line* = left]
            \addplot [] table [x index = {0}, y index = {1}, col sep = comma] {data.dat};
        \end{axis}
        \begin{axis}[axis y line* = right]
            \addplot [] table [x index = {0}, y index = {2}, col sep = comma] {data.dat};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This results in the plot which isn't so bad.

> [image: proper margin]

If I add `xmin =1` and `xmax = 5` to `\pgfplotsset{}` and typeset the document again, margin on the right side becomes obviously larger than the left one.

```
[...]
\pgfplotsset{
    compat = 1.12,
    set layers,
    scale only axis,
    xmin = 1,
    xmax = 5,
}
[...]
```

> [image: improper margin]

I often use `trim axis left (right)` to center the plot in `article` class. So, I tried that also, but it just erased y labels and didn't solve the problem.

I don't know if this is a specification or a bug, I want the both margins to be the same size. Adding `border` option to `standalone` class might help a bit, but it's quite adhoc and seems to be difficult to set the optimal value each time. What should I do?

Comment: Can you add `restrict y to domain=1:5` to the axis?

Comment: @percusse You mean `x` instead of `y`? If so, it worked! Could you post it as an answer when you have time so that I can accept it?

Comment: @percusse Would you like to answer this one as well?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments.